# DML operation on cursor in Oracle OCI or OCCI

Tags: oracle, oracle-call-interface, occi

I have been trying to update a column on a cursor in a resultset after a query is executed. In other words, I am trying to achieve the following type of query in Oracle through OCI/OCCI:

> update [table] set [column_name] = [value] where current of [cursor]

In MS-SQL server it can be done, and through ODBC it can be done in Oracle  also. But it does not seem to be supported by Oracle through OCI or OCCI.
I have only found the following excerpt in the document:

> Oracle does not support DML operations on scrollable cursors.

I do not know what exactly that means: Does that mean not supported only for scrollable cursor or not supported at all.

I am not sure if the Oracle server supports the use of `where current of [cursor name]` query. The ODBC API to get the cursor name is `SQLGetCursorName()`, but there is none in Oracle.

Example:

```
env = Environment::createEnvironment();
conn = env->createConnection(username, password, connectionString);
Statement* stmt = conn->createStatement("select id, name, last_update_date from table1 where id in (1,2,3,4,5)");
ResultSet* rs = stmt->executeQuery();
while (rs->next())
{
    if (rs->getInt(1) == 3)
    {
        //Update the last_update_date column to the current timestamp
    }
}

//Resource cleanup
```

Thanks all!

Comment: It means only scrollable cursors. Maybe you should show the actual code you're using and the error you get.

Comment: I haven't found any API in OCI or OCCI that either update at the cursor or returns the cursor name. The ODBC API to get the cursor name is SQLGetCursorName(), but there is none in Oracle.

Comment: Surely you're declaring the cursor name yourself in OCI? Again, adding your code to the question will help understand what problem you are having.

Comment: Thanks Alex! I have edited the post and added the pseudo code.